# Object reference not set to an instance of an object during xml serialization and problem with selection of combobox item upon loading

Tags: wpf, xml-serialization

question 1. I have this issue of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when my Majorlabel is empty and this occurs after i try to do a save button click on xml serialization. How can i fix this?

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string savepath;
    SaveFileDialog DialogSave = new SaveFileDialog();
    // Default file extension
    DialogSave.DefaultExt = "txt";
    // Available file extensions
    DialogSave.Filter = "XML file (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    // Adds a extension if the user does not
    DialogSave.AddExtension = true;
    // Restores the selected directory, next time
    DialogSave.RestoreDirectory = true;
    // Dialog title
    DialogSave.Title = "Where do you want to save the file?";
    // Startup directory
    DialogSave.InitialDirectory = @"C:/";
    DialogSave.ShowDialog();
    savepath = DialogSave.FileName;
    DialogSave.Dispose();
    DialogSave = null;

    FormSaving abc = new FormSaving();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MajorversionresultLabel.Content.ToString()))
    {
        abc.Majorversion = MajorversionresultLabel.Content.ToString();
    }
    abc.Startzbuildfrom = StartzbuildcomboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

    using (Stream savestream = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
        serializer.Serialize(savestream, abc);
    }
}
```

As recommended,
here is the line of error:

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MajorversionresultLabel.Content.ToString()))
    {
        abc.Majorversion = MajorversionresultLabel.Content.ToString();
    }
```

Question 2. I used this line to save my combo box selection:

```
abc.Startzbuildfrom = StartzbuildcomboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

and in my load i have this line:

```
StartzbuildcomboBox.SelectedItem = abc.Startzbuildfrom
```

why wont it select the combobox selection previously?

Comment: Please: Don't post a wall of code, **Do** post specific information about your problem - the line that the error occurrs on would be a good start! :-)

Comment: Also, one question per question, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that MajorversionresultLabel is null, or MajorversionresultLabel.Content is null. Thus your statement

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MajorversionresultLabel.Content.ToString()))
```

will throw a NullReferenceException. Try this instead:

```
if (MajorversionresultLabel != null && MajorversionresultLabel.Content != null && MajorversionLabel.Content.ToString() != string.Empty)
```

I bet your NullReferenceException will go away.

Answer (score 1):

As a first note, I'd recommend only putting one question into a single query here. Makes it easier.

For your second question, my guess is that you're running into a reference variable problem. I think that calling the ToString() method on the SelectedItem actually creates an entirely new string variable. Then, when you try to set the selected item later, it can't find the new string as a possible item to select because, even though the two strings have the same value, they are different objects. I would maybe recommend that you either:

1) Set the selected item by searching through your combo box contents to find a string whose value matches the one you've saved

or

2) Save the actual reference by saying abc.Startzbuildfrom = StartzbuildcomboBox.SelectedItem. Then set the selected item from that reference.

Comment: Hi aardvarkk, thanks for your reply. I did this: abc.Startzbuildfrom = StartzbuildcomboBox.SelectedItem; but it states "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string' ".. any idea about this?

Comment: oh ok i declared Startzbuildfrom as a string previously.. now it is object and it is ok now. I still have issue though. i will post it in a new post